# Is there Debug Console for blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In smarty, there is `Smarty Debug Console` for display all program details(like this picture). how about blade ? 
if not exists this feature, can we implement that by another way ?
In other words, i want all information like : Server/Request Data, GET Data, POST Data, Files, Cookies, Session, Environment Variables, Registered Handlers  to simply show to other developer.

[image]

Comment: You could use [whoops!](http://filp.github.io/whoops/) which is for cool kids! When there is an error in your PHP template, it's considered a PHP error!

Comment: You want https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar too.

Comment: best answer ceejayoz.

Answer (score 7):

Blade does not have a console. But you can use functions like `var_dump()`

Comment: by default in laravel whoops, when an error occurs all info displayed bottom of the error box. thanks